# Is it possible to tell with the Phonegap Media success callback what triggered it?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there any way to tell what sort of event triggered the success call back of Phonegap Media?  Is it possible to tell if the media was stopped or finished?

Comment: check this doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I checked the docs before asking the question. Pretty sure the docs don't answer the question. Happy to be proved wrong. I am using 2.9.0 atm but happy to update if needed.